# php Zend framework 2 error 404 page

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I was trying to add new error 404 page for my module. I have Application and my own Admin module. For Application I use default 404.phtml, for my new module I created admin404.phtml but I have no idea how to run it. There are a lot of options how to change layout for modules but I couldn`t find answer for my question.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

When a page could not be found or some other error happens inside of your web application,
a standard error page is displayed. The appearance of the error page is controlled by the
error templates. There are two error templates: `error/404` which is used for "404 Page Not Found" error, and `error/index` which is displayed when an unhandled exception is thrown somewhere inside of the application.

The *module.config.php* file contains several parameters under the `view_manager` key, which you can use to configure the appearance of your error templates:

```
<?php
return array(
  //...

  'view_manager' => array(    
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    //...
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',    
    'template_map' => array(
      //...
      'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
      'error/index'=> __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
      __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
  ),
);
```

- The `display_not_found_reason` parameter controls whether to display the detailed
  information about the "Page not Found" error.
- The `display_exceptions` parameter defines whether to display information about
  an unhandled exception and its stack trace.
- The `not_found_template` defines the template name for the 404 error.
- The `exception_template` specifies the template name for the unhandled exception error.

You typically set the `display_not_found_reason` and `display_exceptions` parameters
to `false` in production systems, because you don't want site visitors see the details
about errors in your site. However, you will still be able to retrieve the detailed
information from Apache's `error.log` file.

Comment: This does not really solve the OP's question of different error templates in different modules (as the `view_manager` configuration array you have correctly mentioned is merged on bootstrap). This means which ever module is loaded last will define the error template.